# Append UTM tracking to URLs

Tags: regex

I'm trying to set a custom rule within the catalog settings in Facebook's business manager, I want to append UTM tracking to my product URLs and cannot do this from a find and replace regex function. A unique identifier of my product URLs is that they always end with a number `0-9`. I'm new to regex and can't figure out how to do this, example below for reference:

Existing product URL:

- https://www.example.com/product/12345
- https://www.example.com/product/54321

Appended UTM tracking:

- https://www.example.com/product/12345**?utm_source=askjeeves&utm_medium=cpm**
- https://www.example.com/product/54321**?utm_source=askjeeves&utm_medium=cpm**

Any help on how to write a find and replace regular expression to help me append tracking to help me achieve similar to my example above would be much appreciated!

Image below from where I am trying to input this rule:
[screen grab in FB business manager catalog custom rule settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw1bi.png)

Comment: What does this have to do with regex? You're just appending a string to an url.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't the option to select append from the custom rule settings in FB's business manager. There is the option to find and replace regex however, and thought there must be a way I can achieve this using this option. I've just never really used regex before.

Comment: Find `(?m)$` replace `?utm_source=askjeeves&utm_medium=cpm`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on your .htaccess. Try the following code into your .htaccess file (Create one if you don't have already) and give me a feedback please.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule product/([0-9]+)    product/$1?utm_source=askjeeves&utm_medium=cpm [L]
```

With this code you'll navigate to **www.example.com/product/12345** but the system will see full URL which is **www.example.com/product/12345?utm_source=askjeeves&utm_medium=cpm**

Comment: Thank you for providing this Alexandros, unfortunately I do not have access to my company's website hosting files to try this.

Comment: Then, @Jared there is no way to do that without your system files. Otherwise this would be a big vulnerability issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know facebook's find and replace function, but generally a regex should look like this:

```
(^http.*$)
```

Then replace with:

```
$1?utm_source=askjeeves&utm_medium=cpm
```

You can also try with:

```
\1?utm_source=askjeeves&utm_medium=cpm
```

If facebook follows 'normal' regexes, this should Work.

**Edit**: try these things too, it might Work.

Comment: Thank you Poul - trying this and hitting preview all of the product URLs were replaced with http. However, you're on to something as this half worked. Are there any other 'normal' regexes I could try? I have 1000s of product URLs that will end in a digit, appending/replacing my tracking without disrupting the original part of URL is what I am trying to achieve